# como obtengo los valores dentro de un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Tengo el siguiente objeto, esta contenido por un key `KqTiAo1cC0nmASiGr941`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en un objeto normal solo basta con decir obj.rut y obtengo el rut, pero en este caso esta presente el key padre `-KqTiAo1cC0nmASiGr941`
si quiero obtener el key lo ago con `Object.keys(obj)` pero ¿Como obtengo sus valores hijos? ,que solo quede una variable con

```
{idLiqui: "-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222",
 rut: "179888882",
status:"listo"}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo está estructurado tu objeto?

Comment: como lo muestra la primera imagen

Comment: Quiero entender tu pregunta, indicas que `-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222` es una propiedad de un objeto y que su valor es otro objeto con estructura `{idLiqui: "-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222", rut: "179888882", status:"listo"}`. Es decir, ¿Quieres que el valor de dicha propiedad lo asignes a otra variable?

Comment: si , que `{idLiqui: "-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222", rut: "179888882", status:"listo"}` quede dentro de una variable

Comment: haz probado **obj[Object.keys(obj)].rut**  ?

Comment: @Andrés tu comentario es el más adecuado como respuesta detallando más.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al poder obtener el key del objeto principal `"-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222"` con `Object.keys(obj)`.

Deberías poder almacenar el objeto hijo dentro de una variable de la siguiente manera:

```
var obj_hijo = obj[Object.keys(obj)];
```

Una vez almacenado el contenido del objeto principal en una variable, deberias poder llamar fácil mente su contenido.

```
console.log(obj_hijo.rut);
```

Espero te haya sido de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

Siendo `abc` la variable de tipo `Object`, solo sería necesario acceder a través de `abc["-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222"]`.

```js
var abc = {};
abc["-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222"] = {idLiqui: "-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222", rut: "179888882", status:"listo"};
console.log(abc);
var d = abc["-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222"];
// Para obtener el valor del la propiedad rut
console.log(d.rut) // abc["-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222"].rut
// 179888882
console.log(d.status) // abc["-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I222"].status
// listo
```